# Make some words inside of textarea non editable

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function that inserts some text into a textarea with jquery

```
<a onclick="Quote(<?php echo $id ?>); return false;">Quote</a>
```

The function

```
function Quote(id) {
var text = $('#message').val();

var quotetext = '[quote='+$('#author_'+id).html()+';'+$('#postid'+id).html()+']'+$('#rawpost_' + id).val() + '[/quote]\n';

$('#message').focus().val('').val(quotetext + text);
}

[quote=Santa;1337]ho ho ho are there any nice programmers here?[/quote]
```

I would love if you couldnt edit `[quote=something;2949]` and `[/quote]` the text inbetween should be editable.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's probably possible with regular expressions, event handlers, and a lot of hacky code, the real question is ***if*** you should do it, and I would say no.

Comment: I just realised its stupid, you could just edit it in for example a text document and just paste it. so theres no point really